# jquery for displaying html page

Tags: jquery

i have an pop.html which contains a `<div>`. can i use jquery to dynamically show that popup while loading the MyHome.html Is it possible to include pop.html contents in MyHome.html using jquery. please suggest. thanks

### pop.html

//div section contains body of html. and overlay transparent PopUp.

### MyHome.html

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could reword your question, so that the words aren't all mashed together in a few sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you currently have a popup.html which is a div with some contents you want it to make it part of Myhome.html but not rendered on page load but shown when you need it.

WEll for this you just make the div has part of the page and give it a style attribute of diplay:none.

Now if you want to show the popup in a fancy way you can do something like this:

```
//popup object is your div: select like $("#divId")
//inputObject is relative to the object where you want to show the div. may be a button, hyperlink etc.
popupObject.css("bottom", inputObject.top + yOffset);
popupObject.css("left", inputObject.left + xOffset);
popupObject.show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 300);
```

Comment: thanks user350374 for your answer. i am new to jquery can you suggest me a link for a similar example. what u understood is right. deadline is about to end to please suggest some link .

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to use is the get function

```
$.get('pop.html', function(data) {
    // manipulate data
});
```

The data paramater should contain the HTML contents of your page pop.html. You can parse it as you see fit. Post some code if you need a clearer answer.